# Form Submit URL Formatting

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I have a form which when submitted goes to the url "signup.php?username=xx" where xx is an input field. Instead of this I was wondering if I could get it to go to the following url "signup/xx" where xx is taken from the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Javascript and some type of .htaccess for that. But why don't you use `POST` instead of `GET`?

I don't want `singup?username=sawny&password=1234` in my history.

**EDIT:**

I had done something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("submit[name='foo']").live('submit', function() {

        var usr = $("form input[name='user']").val();
        $("form input[name='user']").remove(); //Else it will be singup/usr?user=

        $("form[name='bar']").attr("action", "singup/"+ usr);
    });
});
```

and then the regexp @zero posted in a .htaccess file.

Comment: I'm only passing the username through therefore I don't mind about the history, I just wanted it to look neater because right now the url it submits to is signup.php?username=xx but I have a rewrite rule for signup/xxx to signup.php?username=xx. Therefore if I can get the form to submit to signup/xx the ht.access will take care of the rest. I hope I make sense

Answer (score 0):

Include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if not already included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then add this script

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr("action");
        var username = $(":input[name='username']").val();
        action = action + "/" + username;
        location.href = action;
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/([^/]*)$ /signup.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have a problem in this end its just getting the form to submit to this url